# Jagged list of lists into a perfect 2d list

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have this jagged python list:
my_list = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8]]]]

---

```
[
    [
        [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5]
        ],
        [
            [6, 7, 8]
        ]
    ]
]
```

---

How do I turn it into this:

```
[[[[1 2 3]
   [4 5 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]

  [[6 7 8]
   [0 0 0]]]]


my_list = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8]]]]
z = [0,0,0]
for i in range(len(a[0])):
  for j in range(len(a[0][i])):
    # if len(a[0][i][j]) != 2:
      a[0][i].append(z)
```

print(a)

giving this:

[[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[6, 7, 8], [0, 0, 0]]]]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could 'pad' each row using something like:

```
mylist.extend([0] * (3 - len(mylist)))
```

Which would pad 'mylist' to 3 elements using 0s.

Possibly useful to write:

```
def padlist(mylist, n, value=0):

    mylist.extend([value] * (n - len(mylist)))
```

Comment: It does not have the (1,3,2,3) shape when I use your code; it adds 0s to the end of the list. Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to apply the function to each of your sublists.